# Are there any better or alternative ways of writing my SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SQL is my "weak" part, however I can handle it. I was wondering if there are better ways of writing my queries below. Any alternative like small tweaks or editing is welcome, it's a way for me to learn more.

I have the expected/correct results on all of them.

**Shows which shops have the product code 1234 giving the code, name and address of them.**

```
SELECT k.ShopCode, Name, Address FROM shops as k
INNER JOIN availability as d ON k.ShopCode=d.ShopCode
WHERE d.ProductCode = '1234';
```

**Shows the average value of transactions in the shop with code 2, including the name, address and the average price of transactions.**

```
SELECT Name, Address, AVG(QUANTITY*ProductPrice) AS AveragePrice
FROM shop AS k
INNER JOIN chashier AS t ON k.ShopCode = t.ShopCode
INNER JOIN buy AS a ON t.CashierCode = a.CashierCode
INNER JOIN contains AS p ON a.BuyCode = p.BuyCode
WHERE t.ShopCode = '1'
GROUP BY NAME, ADDRESS
```

**Shwos the name, address and the amount of the top three in total purchasing customers of the chain.**

```
SELECT TOP 3 BuyerName, BuyerSurname, Address, SUM(QUANTITY*ProductPrice) AS AveragePrice
FROM buyer AS pe
INNER JOIN buy AS a ON pe.CardCode = a.BuyerCode
INNER JOIN contains AS p ON a.BuyCode= p.BuyCode
GROUP BY pe.CardCode, BuyerName, BuyerSurname, Address
ORDER BY AveragePrice DESC;
```

**This one shows the new products that not yet launched in the shops and therefore
not participate in any buy. The answer includes the code and description of the product.**

```
SELECT BuyCode, description from products
WHERE product.BuyCode not in
( select distinct store_has_products.product_id FROM store_has_products)
```

**It shows the manager of each shop. The answer includew the store code and the name of the manager.**

```
SELECT works.store_id as, employee.first_name, employee.last_name FROM manager
left join employee on manager.id = employee.id
lefti join works on employee.id = works. employee_id
```

Comment: The best way to avoid writing SQL queries is to *not write* SQL queries. Not using a SQL database is probably the best way to achieve that.

Comment: You queries look ok, but nobody can really answer your question without knowing how the tables are defined (fields, keys, constraints etc.)

Comment: What are the benefits of having inner join instead of left join ? I think that posting the database will lead into a really really big post. What I am looking for are maybe some little tweaks or editing.

Comment: No `TOP 3` in MySQL. Use `LIMIT 3` instaed.

Comment: Two valid answers, and it got closed.  Seems harsh

Comment: And I thought stackoverflow is a place to ask questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change the 4th query (products that have no launched yet) to use EXISTS...

```
SELECT BuyCode, description FROM products
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM store_has_products WHERE product_id = products.BuyCode)
```

(I've seen very poor performance from using IN over large sets.  That may have improved, I've not used MySQL in ages.  But this is at least an alternative formulation.)

The rest look fine to me...

Comment: Hi there, thank you. Is there any other way of writing `SELECT Name, Address, AVG(QUANTITY*ProductPrice) AS AveragePrice` ?

Comment: The AVG() code looks exactly as I'd have done it.

Answer (score 0):

A 'hot' alternative is ORM (object relational mapping)

Comment: How? He asked for alternatives, I give him an answer.

Comment: He asked for alternative syntax to his queries. And you are not answering that.

Comment: Not sure why this should be a comment.  In OP

>  Any alternative is welcome, it's a way to learn more.

Comment: If by "hot", you mean he may get burned, yes, I agree :)

Comment: Oh, he meant just rewriting his queries. My bad, I guess.

Comment: @ypercube Yeah.. let's just say I meant that ;]. Good luck getting the OPs queries working through ORMs. But you know.. who doesn't like a challenge!

Comment: @Gerben: I haven't downvoted you by the way. ORMs is a (valid or not) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your queries. Just a couple of picks:

- Your aliases are confusing. Why use an alias of 'a' for a table named buy? Aliasing typically uses the first letter of an object and in the case of collision, a meaningful abbreviation.
- Specifying INNER on your joins is overly verbose. JOINs are INNER by default. Same goes for OUTER. LEFT and RIGHT joins are always OUTER
- Your use of the TOP keyword in one of your queries is troublesome as well. What if 5 people tied with the same amount for 2nd place?  Your TOP result would arbitrarily ignore 3 of those 5 keeping the 1st and two 2nds. It's a common trap with TOP.

Comment: Hi thank you for this. So you mean I should only write it like `JOIN buy AS a ON pe.CardCode = a.BuyerCode` removing the INNER ?

Comment: Yes. But also don't forgot your weird aliasing. They are confusing. The INNER thing is less important than proper object naming.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like sql try [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) for PHP.

Comment: He is asking about alternative SQL syntax, and you are guessing at PHP, as he didn't mention it anywhere.

Comment: PHP tag was in first version of question. @ba__friend have erased that tag.